# Inverse of function, containing a fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

This is basic, I know, but I cannot seem to come up with the right answer.

Find the inverse of the function:
$$f(x)= \frac3{x+1}$$

My steps:
1. Convert f(x) to y
$$y = \frac3{x+1}$$

1. Switch places of x and y
   $$x= \frac3{y+1}$$
2. Try to solve for y. So I multiply the denominator by x to get rid of it
   $$x(y+1) = 3$$
3. After multiplying, I'm left with
   $$xy + x = 3$$
4. Which then converts to
   $$2xy = 3$$
5. Then I get rid of `2x` on the left, placing it on the right
   $$y = 3 - 2x$$
6. Now I convert `y` to the inverse function
   $$f^{-1}(x) = 3 - 2x$$

My answer is obviously wrong. The correct answer is:
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{3-x}{x}$$

Where did I mess up?

Thanks!

Comment: Step 4: $xy+x\neq 2xy$

Comment: Man oh man... what a day. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After step 2. you could just divide by $x$ to get
$$y+1 = \frac3x$$
and then subtract $1$ to get
$$y = \frac3x - 1 = \frac{3-x}x$$

Comment: Thanks for this! I see where I messed up (`xy + x` should have then turned into y = 3-x/x). What is the process to "divide by x"? It sounds like I might be doing extra unnecessary steps.

Comment: @WesFoster It's multiplication of both sides by $\frac1x$, of course assuming $x\ne 0$, but since $f(y) \ne 0 \quad\forall\ y\in\mathbb R$, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Step 4 is wrong, check it. instead, divide by x after step 2, and carry over 1.

Comment: This is not a answer. Is a comment.

Comment: The question was "where did I mess up?" I answered that.

Comment: Sorry about your ~answer~.

Answer (score -1):

$XY+X=3
\\XY=3-X
\\Y=(3-X)/X$

This is correct steps after step $3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps readability to format answers using Mathjax and please do not use all caps.